# Running a Selenium Node for IE as WIndows 2003 service

Tags: windows, selenium, internet-explorer-8, webdriver

I can run a Selenium node capable of supporting IE8, Chrome28 and FireFox 22.  My setup works when I run the node through the command line.

HOwever, when I run the node as a Selenium service and run a test for IE.  The test fails with Webdriver throwing Exceptions that it cannot find certain elements on the page.

When tests fail a screenshot is taken.  In the case, of IE tests - the PNG file is just a black square ... where the browser would normally be.

If I run tests against FF and Chrome .. works fine.

So, the problem is isolated to IE.  It only seems to work with a Selenium node when run locally from the commandline .. it does not seem to work when running the node as a Windows service.

Has anyone else had this problem ?

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 0):

The IE driver is not supported being run in a Windows service context. There are too many differences in attempting to run an executable as a service than being run in a standard user context.